# Calculate Average after populating a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been tasked with figuring out the average length of time that our customers stick with us. (Specifically from the date they become a customer, to when they placed their last order.)

I am not 100% sure that I am doing this properly, but my thought was to gather the date we enter the customer into the database, and then head over to the order table and grab their most recent order date, dump them into a temp table, and then figure out the length of time between those two dates, and then tally an average based on that number.

( I have to do some other wibbly wobbly time stuff as well, but this is the one thats kicking my butt)
The end goal with this is to be able to say "On Average our customers stick with us for 4 years, and 3 months." (Or whatever the data shows it to be.)

```
    SELECT * INTO #AvgTable
      FROM(
         SELECT DISTINCT (c.CustNumber) AS [CustomerNumber]
         , COALESCE(convert( VARCHAR(10),c.OrgEnrollDate,101),'') AS [StartDate]
         , COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX(co.OrderDate),101),'')AS [EndDate]
          ,DATEDIFF(DD,c.OrgEnrollDate, co.OrderDate) as [LengthOfTime]

         FROM dbo.Customer c
         JOIN dbo.CustomerOrder co ON c.ID = co.CustomerID

         WHERE c.Archived = 0
         AND co.Archived =0
         AND c.OrgEnrollDate IS NOT NULL
         AND co.OrderDate IS NOT NULL

         GROUP BY c.CustNumber
         , co.OrderDate 2
         )

     --This is where I start falling apart



      Select AVG[LengthofTime]

      From #AvgTable
```

Comment: apart from the technicalities of your sql statement, be careful about the conclusions you draw: some customer who enrolled 4 years ago to place a single order today probably 'sticks' to your company much less than a client visiting your shop for the past 2 months ordering 5 times. at the very least add the variance to your report. better even, incorporate the frequency of orders in your analysis (e.g. aggregate for types of custmers: 'rare visitors', 'john doe', 'power shopper'). all opinions imho, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that since you are storing the data in a temp table, that the integer result of the datediff is being implicitly converted back to a datetime (which you cannot do an average on).

Don't store the average in your temp table (don't even have a temp table, but that is whole different conversation).  Just do the differencing in your select.

Comment: Doesn't DateDiff return an INT? The MSDN says that it does, so I had assumed that when it inserted into the Temp that it would keep it as an Int.

How would you do the above without a Temp Table? It seemed the easiest way to handle this.

Comment: @Barnie: I was assuming that you were stating the structure of the table, but just weren't showing it in your question.  Do a select * from your temp table to check.

Comment: Yea, I just did this, and it works perfectly. I really wanted to just populate it on the fly and not declare it. Thank you for your help! I am unable to upvote yet, but I will mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

If understand you correctly, then just try

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(dd, StartDate, EndDate)) AvgTime
  FROM #AvgTable
```

Comment: I modified the script to put the DateDiff up in the main Insert into the Temp Table.

The AVG section is whats kicking my butt, so that I can pull an AVG of the entire [LengthOfTime] column.

Also, I am getting an odd error when trying to pull any data out of the Temp Table, after inserting it.